# Is there any way to identify what does the value in point cloud text file represent without contacting the one who generated it?

Tags: point, lidar, classification, ascii, point-cloud

I have a point cloud text file that I obtained from the internet and it contain 6 type of value. I assume the first three value represent xyz values but I do not know about what the other three represent. How do I identify what these values represent without contacting the people that made it?

[image: Point cloud text file]

Comment: Unless it's written somewhere, I think the answer is in your question!

Comment: Do you at least know *something* about the point cloud. lidar/photogrametry? range of values? coordinates system?

Comment: Nope, I do not have that information. I am going to try to contact the people that made this point cloud text file as instructed by @Kasper.